# Error connecting to DB from VB to Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have an Access project where I want a label to be showed when a form is opened only if a query returns a result.

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim stSQL As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)

Dim cn As DAO.Connection
Set cn = DAO.Connection


cn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"

cn.Open stdbName
stSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_lessons"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(stSQL1, dbOpenDynaset)

If (rs Is Not Nothing) Then
    If (rs.GetRows() > 0) Then
        lbl_alert.Visible = True
    Else
      lbl_alert.Visible = False
    End If

End If
```

When I try to open the form I'm getting the following error:
      Compile error:
      Method or data member not found

I'm using Access 2007 with VB7

Can someone please help?

Comment: What is VB7 ? And our code seems to be ADO like, rather than DAO. Shouldn't you just change the DAO.Connection into an ADO.Connection ?

Comment: If your're not using Access, just using an MDB from another tool/language, please retag: replace "ms-access" by "Jet"

Answer (score 0):

**Note** - when compile errors happen in VBA, a line of code is always highlighted. Looking carefully at the highlighted line will help you figure out what you did wrong. Also note that you should always compile your code before attempting to run the form. (open the "Debug" menu > click "Compile VBAProject" or the like.)

There appears to be a bunch of problems, and you'll probably have to address them one at a time. just keep fixing issues and re-compiling your code.

1. `1cn.Open stdbName1`
   --> `stdbname` is not defined anywhere in the code you showed us.
2. `Dim stSQL As String`
   --> You defined your connection string as `stSQL` but in your code you used: `stSQL1 = "..."`. Fix your variable name.

Comment: Thank you all for your help; however, I’m still stuck.
I have googled all day but can’t find a good tutorial for this.
I’m trying to do something I haven’t one in about 10 years.. so I apologize for the stupid questions…

I’m trying to connect to my access DB, run a query, and do something with the result set.

Can someone please share a short explanation to how this can be accomplished?

Thank you

Comment: I recommend you upvote this question if it helped you, accept it if it answered your initial question, and then ask a new question if you need any additional help on something else. I personally don't have a tutorial on connecting to Access Databases.